# Appending an array of objects to FormData in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data, form-data

I know this question has been a dozen times, but I just can't seem to get any of the answers to work.

I have an app with a React frontend and Django Rest backend, and I'm trying to send an array of objects in a request. I've gotten this to work in Postman in both the raw JSON input as well as the FormData there:

[image]

[image]

So I know that my backend should be able to handle it fine, but no matter what I try in my React code I get the same 400 error. Here is my (slightly trimmed) function from my front end:

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    if(data.photo.length >= 1) {
        formData.append('photo', data.photo[0]);
    }
    formData.append('recipe_name', data.recipe_name);

    formData.append('ingredients', JSON.stringify(data.ingredients));
    
    // data.ingredients.forEach(element => {
    //     console.log(JSON.stringify(element))
    //     formData.append('ingredients[]', JSON.stringify(element))
    // });

    // for(let i=0; i < data.ingredients.length; i++) {
    //     console.log(data.ingredients[i])
    //     formData.append('ingredients[]', JSON.stringify(data.ingredients[i]))
    // }

    console.log(formData)

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('access_token') ?
            'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token') :
            null,
        },
    };
    axiosInstance.post('/recipes/', formData, config).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        navigate('/recipe/' + response.data.id);
    });
```

I left some commented out code of different things I've tried, but to summarize, I've tried:

```
formData.append('ingredients', data.ingredients);

formData.append('ingredients', JSON.stringify(data.ingredients));

formData.append('ingredients[]', JSON.stringify(data.ingredients));

data.ingredients.forEach(element => {
    formData.append('ingredients[]', JSON.stringify(element))
});

data.ingredients.forEach(element => {
    formData.append('ingredients', JSON.stringify(element))
});

data.ingredients.forEach(element => {
    formData.append('ingredients', element)
});

data.ingredients.forEach(element => {
    formData.append('ingredients[]', element)
});
```

I've even tried doing a traditional for-loop with the same permutations, but to no success.

I've also tried looking into the data itself that I'm sending from the front end, but as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with it either. Here is the raw data coming from my form component:

[image]

and the individual elements (printed out in the forEach loop):

[image]

and those same elements passed through JSON.stringify()

[image]

I'm really at a loss on what else to try, it feels like I've basically tried everything, and all of the answers for this same question I've found on previous threads all suggests what I've tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `data.ingredients` an array of [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Comment: No it's an array of the objects shown in the last couple screenshots

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add it as a json file blob:

```js
var jsonObject = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3'
};

var jsonBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(jsonObject)], { type: 'application/json' });

formData.append('jsonFile', jsonBlob, 'data.json');
```

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately got the same results as my other attempts

Answer (score 0):

When you send data in a POST (or any other method) request, the data is in the body of the request. You can send data with any content-type, but typically you will use either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or any other text format (the first are also text formats...) like `application/json`, `text/xml` etc.

If you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` all entries are key/value pairs. JSON can be send as a string as one of the values. If you use `multipart/form-data` all entries are also key/value pairs, but you have more options like sending files, and a file can have a name and a content-type. So, either you send JSON as a string in a key/value pair or as a file (just like Cassiano Franco write [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77291446/322084)). The FormData object can be used for preparing `multipart/form-data` content. So, by using the FormData object, JSON is either as string to a key/value pair or as a file.

The last option is to send everything as text, like `application/json`. So, the content-type of the request is `application/json` and the body of the request is as string created based on something like `JSON.stringify(jsonObject)`.

Receiving a POST request on the server side with any of the above mentioned content-types will look different. So, depending on the content-type you need to handle data and files in different ways.

This is just the long argument for me to give Cassiano Franco a vote.

Comment: His answer didn't work, though. The content type for my request needs to be multipart/form-data because image files are sent in this request as well

Comment: @Chowdahhh so, you are down to two options. Either add the JSON as a string to a key/value pair or add another "file" being the JSON blob.

Comment: Have I not already tried both of those in my attempts or in trying Cassiano's answer?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a fix, though I'm not convinced this is the overall "correct" way to do this. Basically, it seems that something with how the array was getting formatted on the frontend was getting it excluded from Django's validated_data. There's clearly something I'm missing considering the form-data works in Postman, but as I wasn't getting any closer otherwise I ended up just decoding the request myself to get the array of values. Of course this created a whack-a-mole effect, working when I send the request from my React frontend but then gave an error when sending the requests from Postman that worked before, so I ended up just checking if the validated_data contained the 'ingredients' field, to let me both make these POST requests in my UI as well as Postman

serializers.py, in my RecipeSerializer:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):

    if 'ingredients' in validated_data:
        ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
    else:
        ingredients_data_str = self.context['request'].POST.get('ingredients', '[]')
        ingredients_data = json.loads(ingredients_data_str)

    recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for ingredient_data in ingredients_data:
        Ingredient.objects.create(recipe=recipe, **ingredient_data)
    return recipe
```